# Retrieving Etag of an s3 object using boto3 client

Tags: amazon-s3, checksum

There is a scenario where I need to verify the checksum(md5) of a file stored in s3 bucket. This can be achieved when uploading the file by specifying the checksum value in the metadata of api call. But in my case, I wanted to verify the checksum after put the data into bucket programmatically. Every object in S3 will have attribute called 'ETag' which is the md5 checksum calculated by S3.

Is there anyway to get the ETag of a specific object and compare the checksum of both local file & file stored in s3 using boto3 client in a python script?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Boto3 api has provided a way to get the metadata of an object stored in s3. The following snippet will help to get the metadata via programmatically :

```
>>> s3_cli = boto3.client('s3')
>>> s3_resp = s3_cli.head_object(Bucket='ventests3', Key='config/ctl.json')
>>> print pprint.pprint(s3_resp)
>>> pp.pprint(s3_resp)
{u'AcceptRanges': 'bytes',
 u'ContentLength': 4325,
 u'ContentType': 'binary/octet-stream',
 u'ETag': '"040c003386f1e2001816d32f2125d07a"',
 u'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 20, 7, 15, 3, tzinfo=tzutc()),
 u'Metadata': {},
 'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPHeaders': {'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
                                      'content-length': '4325',
                                      'content-type': 'binary/octet-stream',
                                      'date': 'Thu, 20 Sep 2018 07:20:53 GMT',
                                      'etag': '"040c003386f1e2001816d32f2125d07a"',
                                      'last-modified': 'Thu, 20 Sep 2018 07:15:03 GMT',
                                      'server': 'AmazonS3',
                                      'x-amz-id-2': 'P2wapOciWCKPfol2sBgoo11tRdr4KwKcDJ/nHW7LZn00mvKfMYyfAPPV2tIcf3Vu+lrV57NBARY=',
                                      'x-amz-request-id': '42AF970E7C9AA18C'},
                      'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
                      'HostId': 'P2wapOciWCKPfol2sBgoo11tRdr4KwKcDJ/nHW7LZn00mvKfMYyfAPPV2tIcf3Vu+lrV57NBARY=',
                      'RequestId': '42AF970E7C9AA18C',
                      'RetryAttempts': 0}}

>>> s3obj_etag = s3_resp['ETag'].strip('"')
>>> print s3obj_etag
'040c003386f1e2001816d32f2125d07a'
```

The **head_object()** method in s3 client object will fetch the metadata (headers) of a given object stored in the s3 bucket.

Answer (score 8):

Do not use the ETag of an object in a bucket to determine object equivalence for an object in another bucket (with the same key). In some experiments, I found for large objects the ETag is not consistent from region to region.  For example, a large file in a bucket in us-east-1 may have a different ETag when it is copied to us-east-2.  The consistency of the ETag value from bucket to bucket varies from object to object.  I saw where some large objects do have the same ETag in both regions. I resorted to creating my own tags with the md5sum in it and when I copy an object from one bucket to another, I also copy the tags.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Van Sickel. Can I use to determine object equivalence within the same bucket?

Comment: Its not exactly a bucket to bucket issue, instead, if the object was created using multipart uploads (=threads uploading big files), ETag is calculated as the MD5 of the MD5s of each of the parts. So you have to know the chunks that went into the multipart upload or rederive them from the chunk size (ugh)

Comment: Well, bucket to bucket issue is also present if at least one of buckets uses encryption, see this question for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67171693/why-would-an-s3-objects-etag-change-under-a-copy . ETag issues are nicely summarized in this feature request: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk/issues/89

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the above code will generate error as if there is a missing parameter.

This works for me

```
s3.meta.client.head_bucket(Bucket='mybucket')
```