# Why would an S3 object's ETag change under a copy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to perform an S3 sync between prefixes in buckets in different accounts using boto3.  My attempt proceeds by listing the objects in the source bucket/prefix in account A, listing the objects in the destination bucket/prefix in account B, and copying those objects in the former that have an ETag not matching the ETag of an object in the latter.  This seems like the right way to do it.

But, it seems that even if the copy operation is successful, the ETag of the destination object is different each time I perform a copy.  Specifically,

```py
>>> # Here is the source object: {'Key': 'blah/blah/file_20210328_232250.parquet', 'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 28, 23, 38, 2, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'ETag': '"ba230f7a358cf1bee6c98250089da435"', 'Size': 52319, 'StorageClass': 'STANDARD'}
>>> client.copy_object(
CopySource={"Bucket": "source-bucket-in-acct-a", "Key": "blah/blah/file_20210328_232250.parquet"),
Bucket="dest-bucket-in-acct-b",
Key="blah/blah/file_20210328_232250.parquet"
)
... 'CopyObjectResult': {'ETag': '"84f11f744cf996e16a3af0d6d2fbee07"', 'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 20, 2, 23, 40, tzinfo=tzutc())}}
```

Notice that the ETag has changed.  If I run the copy again, it will have yet again a different ETag.  I've tried all manner of additional parameters to the copy request (`MetadataDirective="COPY"`, etc.).  I might be missing a thing that preserves ETag, but my understanding is that ETag is derived from the object's data, not its metadata.

Now, it says in the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CopyObjectResult.html) that the ETags are *identical for a successful non-multipart copy operation*, which this is, but this does not seem to be the case.  It is not a multipart copy and I've checked the actual data; they are identical.  Hence, my question:

How can an object's ETag change, if not for an unsuccessful copy?

Comment: That's should work. Does it happen only for this one particular object? Have you tried on anything else?

Comment: @Marcin It happens with every object in the interested prefix.  I know this because the "sync" copies every object under the prefix upon a rerun, since the etags are different between source and destination (this is the only condition in the code to test for, "is this object already in the destination").  

Do you think it has anything to do with encryption?  I.e., source object encrypted with account A's KMS key, destination encrypted with account B's.  I have no idea if that makes sense.  I would think that doesn't matter, but I am stumped.  That's why I'm asking here.

Comment: In [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/data-integrity-s3/) they write that depending on encryption, different algorithm may be used. So maybe this could explain your issue?

Comment: @Marcin Yeah, that seems like the only explanation.

Comment: If you don't mind I will provide an answer with the link an a bit of info.

Comment: @Marcin Sure, I'll go ahead and accept because, even though I don't have a definitive answer, this has to be the reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments.

Calculation of Etag hash for an object is not consistent and can't be fully used for checking integrity of the objects. From [AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/data-integrity-s3/):

> ETag isn't always an MD5 digest, it **can't always be used for verifying** the integrity of uploaded files.

This is because the calculations of ETag [depend](http://%20ETag%20isn%27t%20always%20an%20MD5%20digest,%20it%20can%27t%20always%20be%20used%20for%20verifying%20the%20integrity%20of%20uploaded%20files.) on how object was created and encrypted:

> Whether the ETag is an MD5 digest depends on how the object was **created and encrypted**.

Comment: [Here's](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_Object.html) another link which says specifically that the entity tag is not a hash of the object's contents when it is encrypted with KMS (in my case, this is true).  They don't say what the etag represents in this case, only that it doesn't represent the contents of the object.  But anyway, this object is decrypted with one KMS key (in account A), and then encrypted with a different KMS key (in account B), so I should apparently expect the entity tags to be different.

Comment: @user4601931 Thanks. The encryption must be most likely explanation for the differences observed. Different KMS keys  used for the two objects.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://teppen.io/2018/10/23/aws_s3_verify_etags/#calculating-an-s3-etag-using-python

Note: if you simply copy the file via AWS s3 web console, partsize is 16MB.

Mickey